# How do I add Batteries to the dependency in dune-project?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I am wondering how to add Batteries to the dependency of the `dune-project` file.

It seems the relevant part is:

```
(package
 ...
 (depends ocaml dune **here?**)
 ...)
```

but I have no idea what I should put there.

Answer (score 0):

I edited bin/dune so that libraries contain batteries and that worked. :)